# Как использовать токены?(Json, android)

Tags: android, json

я только недавно начал разбираться как работать с Json с помощью android-studio и так как я не слишком подкован в работе с серверами, у меня возникли некоторые проблемы с загрузкой картинки и пониманием как точно нужно работать с токенами. На сколько я понял, по сути токен это зашифрованные данные для авторизации на сервере. У меня получилось получить токен с сервера, но вот как его использовать не понимаю и подозреваю, что из-за этого и не получается загружать картинку на сервер. Пожалуйста подскажите, как правильно это реализовать и какие ошибки я допускаю, буду очень благодарен за любую помощь.
Вот код:

```
public void sendPost() {
        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    URL url = new URL(urls);
                    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
                    conn.setRequestProperty("Accept","application/json");
                    conn.setDoOutput(true);
                    conn.setDoInput(true);

                    JSONObject jsonParam = new JSONObject();
                    jsonParam.put("username", UserLogin);
                    jsonParam.put("password", UserPassword);
                    Log.i("JSON", jsonParam.toString());
                    DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
                    //os.writeBytes(URLEncoder.encode(jsonParam.toString(), "UTF-8"));
                    os.writeBytes(jsonParam.toString());
                os.flush();
                os.close();

                String resultJson = "";
                InputStream inputStream = conn.getInputStream();
                StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

                BufferedReader reader = null;
                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    buffer.append(line);
                }

                resultJson = buffer.toString();
                dataJsonObj = new JSONObject(buffer.toString());
                String ClientToken = dataJsonObj.getString("token");


                Log.d(LOG_TAG, ClientToken);

                Log.i("STATUS", String.valueOf(conn.getResponseCode()));
                Log.i("MSG" , conn.getRequestMethod());


                url = new URL(url_for_loading_image);
                conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Accept","application/json");
                conn.setDoOutput(true);
                conn.setDoInput(true);

                JSONObject jsonParam2 = new JSONObject();

                jsonParam2.put("photo", toBase64(bitmap));
                jsonParam2.put("collect", "32221");
                jsonParam2.put("user_comment", "3222");
                Log.i("JSON", jsonParam2.toString());
                DataOutputStream os2 = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
                //os.writeBytes(URLEncoder.encode(jsonParam.toString(), "UTF-8"));
                os2.writeBytes(jsonParam2.toString());
                os2.flush();
                os2.close();

                Log.i("STATUS", String.valueOf(conn.getResponseCode()));
                Log.i("MSG" , conn.getRequestMethod());

                conn.disconnect();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    thread.start();
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

Обычно токен передают либо в заголовке либо в каком то параметре, чтобы авторизовать вашу сессию. Токен может быть долгоживущим, так что его надо сохранять в памяти или SharedPreferences. Уточните у бэкендщиков, на картинке он не упомянут.

На сервере судя по всему Django так что там делают обычно так:
http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#tokenauthentication

```
conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Token " + ClientToken);
```

Comment: примерно так:

conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    conn.setDoOutput(true);
                    conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Token " + ClientToken);
                    OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
                    JSONObject jsonParam2 = new JSONObject();
                    DataOutputStream os2 = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
os2.writeBytes(jsonParam2.toString());
writer.flush();

Comment: Использовать HttpURLConnection в 2018 это прям  не принятая практика. Как это делать с retrofit (де факто стандарт для работы с REST, даже Google уже примеры на нем делает) https://medium.com/@techexe/retrofit-interceptor-add-authorization-token-c1e9a3035de7

Comment: И еще чтобы точно проверить поставьте Postman и сделайте сначала запрос вручную и убедитесь что он работает. https://www.getpostman.com/